# Steam API with PHP from JSON

Tags: php, json, steam

I don't know much PHP at all and I am not to sure how I call a specific element of the Steam API JSON

The JSON Output is...

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198059606697",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "Nerve | RainDrops",
            "lastlogoff": 1481147845,
            "commentpermission": 1,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/finalfront/",
            "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/653e72d21d87b59b7ddb8c90422aace354124c1b.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/653e72d21d87b59b7ddb8c90422aace354124c1b_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/653e72d21d87b59b7ddb8c90422aace354124c1b_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 4,
            "primaryclanid": "103582791456413210",
            "timecreated": 1330551594,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "US"
        }
    ]

}
}
```

The PHP is...

```
<?php
$steamkey = "";
$id_user = "76561198059606697";

$apifr = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamkey."&steamid=".$id_banuser."&avatar";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$apifr);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I want to call the "Avatarfull" link and im not quite sure how to do it. I must use CRUL.
the current PHP Code does not output any errors. nor does it output anything

Comment: You need the link in `PHP` or you can use `AJAX`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_decode` to make an array of objects from that:

`$result = json_decode($result);`

and then get the link like this:

```
echo $result->response->players[0]->avatarfull
```

Or if you have multiple elements, you can loop through:

```
$result = json_decode($result);
$result = $result->response->players;
foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r->avatarfull;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Please refer to [this link](http://ideone.com/MjKD4b) to see it in action.

Or [this link](http://ideone.com/6XBS4t) for the second example.

In your code would look something like this:

```
<?php
$steamkey = "";
$id_user = "76561198059606697";

$apifr = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$steamkey."&steamid=".$id_banuser."&avatar";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$apifr);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result);
$result = $result->response->players;

foreach($result as $r){
    echo $r->avatarfull;
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130143/discussion-on-answer-by-ionut-steam-api-with-php-from-json).

Comment: ^^ Sorry didnt have discussion due to rep

Comment: Hi again @RainDrops, have you tried entering the chat room?

Comment: Yea, I can enter it now

Answer (score 0):

you need do something like this

```
<?php

// this part obviously is do it by your curl call
$result = '{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198059606697",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "Nerve | RainDrops",
            "lastlogoff": 1481147845,
            "commentpermission": 1,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/finalfront/",
            "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/653e72d21d87b59b7ddb8c90422aace354124c1b.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/653e72d21d87b59b7ddb8c90422aace354124c1b_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/65/653e72d21d87b59b7ddb8c90422aace354124c1b_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 4,
            "primaryclanid": "103582791456413210",
            "timecreated": 1330551594,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "US"
        }
    ]

}
}';

//lets work with this data

$res = json_decode($result);

if(isset($res->response->players[0])){
    print_r($res->response->players[0]->avatar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to decode json and transform him to array.

```
$structure = json_decode($result, true);

// Array of players.
$players = $structure['response']['players'];

foreach($players as $row) {
    echo $row['avatarfull'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: @Emiliano yes it is. Read again the **json_decode** documentation and what the second parameter **true** do.

Comment: " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" "/avatar.php on line 25" which is "foreach($players as $row) {"